# Diffing 2 large directories for file existence differences

Tags: linux, unix, diff

I'm trying to recursively diff 2 directories with lots of hierarchy/files within them. It's overwhelming to parse through the results.

What I'd like is a simple summary report that shows what's in one directory but not the other.  I can write a simple perl script to do it, but wondering if I'm missing some obvious solution.

**Edit:** I found this thread: [Given two directory trees, how can I find out which files differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997693/given-two-directory-trees-how-can-i-find-out-which-files-differ) and something like this seems to work:

```
diff --brief -r dir1/ dir2/ |grep -v differ
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `diff`?

```
diff <(find dirA | sort) <(find dirB | sort) >bigdiff
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997693/given-two-directory-trees-how-can-i-find-out-which-files-differ

Answer (score 0):

Try this scriptlet (modified tripleee's answer)

```
diff <(find prod/ | sort | cut -d"/" -f2- ) <(find test/ | sort| cut -d"/" -f2-)
```

The cut removes the directory names themselves in  my case "prod" and "test"
 Tip: Add the -y to see a side by side view