# Difference between 2 maven repositories

Tags: maven

2 Maven Repositories - repA, repB. 
repA is getting decommissioned. 
Multiple applications depend currently on both repA,repB.

What is the quickest way to identify jars which are on repA but not on repB ? 
Also, would be perfect if repA and repB have the same versions of a given jar- we can compare the md5 so that we can show diffs & prompt those applications for additional testing.

Alternative solution might be show all jars(version,md5) under a repository.

Comment: *are on repA* , do you mean repA is dependent on here or those which depends on repA?

Comment: RepA,B totally separate. Apps depend on both currently

Comment: does `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree`  (`mvn dependency:tree`) for both repA and repB solves your problem?

Comment: if your repositories are file-based, this page can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997693/given-two-directory-trees-how-can-i-find-out-which-files-differ

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn project-info-reports:dependencies
```

this will generate a reporting html in /target/site/dependencies.html

you can check the information in `Dependency Repository Locations`
[image]

[more about the plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html)