# How can I do a recursive "diff check" on a large project?

Tags: diff

I am looking for a way to be able to perform a "diff check" between two very similar large projects. I want to easily be able to search for differences in all the files in the root directory and the files in the directories within the root directory and so on.

Is there a program that offers such functionality?

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997693/given-two-directory-trees-how-can-i-find-out-which-files-differ-by-content

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of 3rd party diffing solutions out there. There's no point writing your own.

If you have git available, then I recommend taking advantage of it. You can call git commands from your own applications as well. The command you might be interested in is [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

An example of using git to accomplish this: [Given two directory trees, how can I find out which files differ by content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997693/given-two-directory-trees-how-can-i-find-out-which-files-differ-by-content)

In my own projects, I have used the C# library [DiffPlex](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DiffPlex) to perform text diffs in an ASP.NET Core web application.