# Search text files with matching names in different directories

Tags: linux, bash

I have two directories, today and yesterday.  Inside each directory are 100+ files with the same exact name, in .cfg format.  In a bash script I can call out a specific file name, and run a diff, and my output is any text within the file that is different from the other.

```
    diff PROD/Today/Core.cfg PROD/Yesterday/Core.cfg > PROD/Changes/delta.txt
```

I know that I need to create a loop to get each individual file name, then compare it with the file with the same name in the other folder.

```
    for i in PROD/Today/*.cfg; do diff PROD/Today/$i PROD/Yesterday/$i > PROD/Changes/delta.txt
```

But this just results in it looking for *.cfg, not the actual file name.

And

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.cfg' | while read -r file; do  
    file=$(basename $file)
    diff PROD/Today/$file PROD/Yesterday/$file > PROD/Changes/$file_delta.txt
done
```

Only results in PROD/Yesterday/.cfg:  No such file or directory, even though the  shows each individual of the 100 file names.

Comment: You can just do `diff PROD/Today PROD/Yesterday` and it will compare each file.

Comment: `$i` contains the directory part, so `PROD/Today/$i` will contain the directory twice. Use `diff "$i" "PROD/Yesterday/$(basename "$i")"`

Comment: So that only compares the file names to see if it exists or not, not the contents of the file.

Comment: `diff -r` compares the content (recursively).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given two directory trees, how can I find out which files differ by content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997693/given-two-directory-trees-how-can-i-find-out-which-files-differ-by-content)

Comment: When I use diff PROD/Today/ PROD/Yesterday > PROD/Changes/delta.txt, my output is:  Only in PROD/Today/: <each individual filename>.cfg with a line for each individual file.  So its comparing the file itself, not the contents of each file.

Comment: @tink That asks how to get just the filenames, not the differences in contents.

Comment: @bgorton Add the `-r` option like tink said

Comment: So basically you are looking for files with the same name in two directories? If you can guarantee that you never have files where the name contains a newline character, you could create two sorted text files holding the names in thos two directories, and then use `comm` to find the common entries. See _man comm_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Barmar said, the problem with your first solution is that the '$i' variable will include the entire path (e.g. PROD/Today/Core.cfg). To get the diff to work, you need to get the basename of $i and use that with the second argument to diff:

```
for i in PROD/Today/*.cfg; do
 file=$(basename $i); diff $i PROD/Yesterday/$file > PROD/Changes/${file}_delta.txt
done
```

Note that I also used that in the destination filename, to make the delta file be unique for each common file name.

To fix your second solution, your find should start at "PROD/Today" not ".", and have a -maxdepth of 2 not 1 (or get rid of that). Oh, and you need curly braces around "file" when creating the delta filename. For example:

```
find PROD -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '*.cfg' | while read -r file; do  
    file=$(basename $file)
    diff PROD/Today/$file PROD/Yesterday/$file > PROD/Changes/${file}_delta.txt
done
```