# Script to determine directory 'diff'

Tags: command-line, diff, md5sum

I have two directories which are different versions of the same software package. I'd like to list all the files/directories that have changed between the two then copy those differences to a new directory.

I've been trying different scripts with `md5sum` and `diff -Nurq` but haven't been able to get the result I'm looking for.

Any recommendations?

**Edit**:

I originally tried taking `md5sum`s, but that didn't seem to work especially if new files were missing.

Next I tried a loop like this:

```
for x in `diff -Nurq ./dir1/ ./dir2/ | awk -F" " '{print $4}'`
do 
  mkdir -vp ./dir_1_2_upgrade/$x; 
  cp $x ./dir_1_2_upgrade/$x
done
```

But that ended up making a bunch of directories and no files.

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: your method of copying files that have changes will never capture deletions, is that a bad thing?

Comment: @larsmans, I think it's a good thing as I want to provide users with the option to add new stuff, but not clobber anything they might have built up before.  Handling deletions sounds more complicated, right?

Comment: fwiw as an option to `diff`, the `git diff` can work outside a git repo and used as a generic `diff` utility, and the generic `patch -p1` utility can be used to apply that patch. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69117565/127971 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945988/127971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
source=SOME_DIR
dest=OTHER_DIR

# TODO: rewrite as awk script
delta=`diff -ur $source $dest`
deleted=`echo "$delta" | grep "^Only in ${source}:" | sed "s/^Only in ${source}: //"`
added=`echo "$delta"   | grep "^Only in ${dest}:"   | sed "s/^Only in ${dest}: //"`
changed=`echo "$delta" | grep '^\+\+\+' | awk '{print $2}'`

echo $deleted
echo $added
echo $changed
```

works if filenames contain no spaces. If you want this to be as general as possible, check out the source for a program such as [`git-diff`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=diff.c;h=ba5f7aa2173a7494b56395bfd88ab6228b5ed1fe;hb=HEAD).