# Git apply patch to specific file outside of git repo

Tags: git, patch, git-patch

I have two files, `x_original.txt` and `x_updated.txt`.

I used the following command to obtain a patch file:

```
git diff --no-index x_original.txt x_updated.txt > fix_something.patch
```

I now want to apply this patch to a file called `x.txt`.

The following is worth noting:

- `x.txt` is not in a git repo
- the filenames `x_original.txt` and `x_updated.txt` are included in `fix_something.patch` which makes no sense because these files won't exist when I'm applying the patch

What git command can I use to apply this patch? Or another utility if necessary? And what modifications should I make to the patch file?

Comment: `x_original.txt` makes sense as the file you apply the patch to would need to be equal the `x_original.txt`, as it was, when the patch-file was made.

Comment: @andlrc I want to apply it to a file regardless of it's name.

Comment: I understand that, I was just stating that you need to know which file the patch was made from, in order to know which file to apply it to. In your case you don't look at the filename as you can just provide the file that needs to be patches, as shown in your answer below.

Comment: @andlrc Yes that was the idea :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16527024/1541397) how to do it using the `patch` command:

```
patch -p1 x.txt fix_something.patch
```

This utility appears to ignore the filenames specified in the patch file, so there's no need to modify anything there.