# Is it possible to compare two directories in Git

Tags: git, diff, meld

I have installed [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) as diff tool in Git. Is it possible to compare two folders using Git or any other way? I tried the following command but nothing happened.

```
git diff /c/sample/folder1/ /c/sample/folder2/
```

Comment: How "nothing happen"? It is expected to work.

Comment: It works, only when both the folders are git projects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to compare two directories on your disk, no need for `git` :

```
# use any suitable diff viewer : meld, kdiff3 ...
meld /c/sample/folder1/ /c/sample/folder2/
```

If you want to have a directory view for the diff between two commits in git :

```
git difftool -d <commit1> <commit2>

# you can also restrict this directory view to a subdir of your repo :
git difftool -d <commit1> <commit2> -- lib/
```

---

[update] to answer @DamianBirchler comment:

to compare two directories within a commit:

```
git difftool -d <commit>:path/to/dir1 <commit>:path/to/dir2
```

This actually works with any two commits (anything that points to two trees within git actually):

```
git difftool -d <commit1>:config  <commit2>:new/path/to/config
```

Comment: `Meld` is not working on Apple M1 Laptop for me unfortunately, since it is keep crashing.

Comment: @Happy: I meant you can use any graphical diff viewer: `kdiff3`, Beyond Compare, ... you name it

Comment: Is it possible to get both? Compare **two different** directories in the same repo **at the same commit** using `git`. What I'm hoping to get from this as compared to using `Meld` is for the "last modified" times to be informed by git (as in "last commit" and by who) as opposed to the OS's idea of last modified. I hope I'm making any sense here.

Answer (score 4):

It actually is perfectly normal to compare different *versions* of folders in a git repository using `git diff master..yourbranch path/to/folder` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791854/diffing-between-two-entire-directories-projects) question).

If it's not about versions, but just comparing two folders, meld can do it:

> Meld lets you compare two or three folders side-by-side. You can start
>   a new folder comparison by selecting the File ▸ New... menu item, and
>   clicking on the Directory Comparison tab.

(from [here](http://meldmerge.org/help/folder-mode.html)).

Comment: Also, if you want to use Git to compare two arbitrary folders, you can use the --no-index option: ```git diff --no-index dir1 dir2```

Comment: @padawin with the real answer to the question!